# How do i get angularjs to bind on a failed request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an application which makes use of angularjs in combination with app-manifest and local storage.

Here is the code for my controller:

```
var ErrandListController = function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.url = 'Errands/GetErrandList';
    $scope.content = [];

    $scope.fetchContent = function ()
    {
        $http.get($scope.url).then(function (result)
        {
            $scope.content = result.data;
            localStorage.setItem("ErrandList", JSON.stringify(result.data));
        }).catch(function (response)
        {
            $scope.content = localStorage["ErrandList"];
        });
    }

    $scope.fetchContent();
}
```

When i make a request to the server and the server is unavailable i obviously does not get a response and angularjs executes the catch-callback and thereby gets the list of errands from local storage and puts it in the scope.

This works fine but the problem is that angularjs seems to stop databinding as soon as a request has failed.

Is it possible to either force data-binding in the catch-callback or set a configuration-flag which tells angularjs to continue databinding in the event of a failed request?
Or is there any other solution to my problem?

Comment: Just a quick hint: You use `JSON.stringify` to serialize the data into localStorage. You need to deserialize it with `JSON.parse` in the catch block.

Comment: And that ofcourse solved my entire problem!
Another relatively obvious problem solved.
The angularjs-team really needs to improve their error reporting though.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i stringified an object before putting it in local storage without parsing it when retrieving it again.
The reason i did not find it at first was that i tried to access a non-existing member of the scope without AngularJS reporting an error.

The moral of the story is that you should always check what is in your scope before assuming there is something wrong with the databinding.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly

```
 $http.get($scope.url).then(function (result){}, function (error) {})
```

Comment: Look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) (section about "The Promise API"): You can specify a separated catch block.

Comment: This works too but it is essentially the same as the code i already had.
The problem was solved thanks to mrak's comment though.